# TrendRaster in R

Tags: r, raster

I would like to calculate a trend of my annual  NPP Rasterbrick (11 files).

this is what my code  looks like :

```
trend.npp = TrendRaster(NPP_corrected, start = c(2010,1), freq = 1, method = 'AAT')
```

> Error in cut.default(cycle(y), if (sbins > 1) sbins else frequency(y) *  :    invalid amount of intervalls

I feel like my code is correct and don´t exactly know how to resolve this issue.

I would like to do the same with my NDVI rasterbrick (55 files)

```
trend.ndvi<- TrendRaster(ndvi_corrected, start=c(2010, 5), freq=23, method="STM")
```

but that takes over 3h to calculate and i dont want to start without knowing that the code works.